# Why scan 1D Barcode only get result in middle of view by Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have a question about scan 1D barcode. Why I set the yellow border about scanning region view, only I put it in the middle of the region and get the result successfully?

It works fine when I put my 1D barcode in the green region by the following image. When I put the red region, and nothing happens. My app orientation only right and left.

What's wrong with my code?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    
    var scanRectView:UIView!
    var device:AVCaptureDevice!
    var input:AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    var output:AVCaptureMetadataOutput!
    var session:AVCaptureSession!
    var preview:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.configureVideoOrientation()
    }
    
    fileprivate func configureVideoOrientation() {
        
        let previewLayer = self.preview
        
        if let connection = previewLayer?.connection {
            
            let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
            
            if connection.isVideoOrientationSupported, let videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: orientation.rawValue) {
                
                previewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
                connection.videoOrientation = videoOrientation
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        
        do{
            self.device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
            
            self.input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            
            self.output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            
            self.session = AVCaptureSession()
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height < 500 {
                self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
            }else{
                self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
            }
            
            self.session.addInput(self.input)
            self.session.addOutput(self.output)
            
            self.output.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr, .ean8, .ean13, .pdf417, .code128, .aztec, .code39, .code39Mod43, .code93, .dataMatrix, .face, .interleaved2of5, .itf14, .upce]
            
            let windowSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
            let scanSize = CGSize(width:windowSize.width*1/3, height:windowSize.width*1/3)
            var scanRect = CGRect(x:(windowSize.width-scanSize.width)/2,
                                  y:(windowSize.height-scanSize.height)/2,
                                  width:scanSize.width, height:scanSize.height)
            
            scanRect = CGRect(x:scanRect.origin.y/windowSize.height,
                              y:scanRect.origin.x/windowSize.width,
                              width:scanRect.size.height/windowSize.height,
                              height:scanRect.size.width/windowSize.width);
            self.output.rectOfInterest = scanRect
            
            self.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session:self.session)
            self.preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            self.preview.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.preview, at:0)
            
            self.scanRectView = UIView();
            self.view.addSubview(self.scanRectView)
            self.scanRectView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:scanSize.width,
                                             height:scanSize.height);
            self.scanRectView.center = CGPoint( x:UIScreen.main.bounds.midX,
                                                y:UIScreen.main.bounds.midY)
            self.scanRectView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
            self.scanRectView.layer.borderWidth = 5;
            
            self.session.startRunning()
            
            do {
                try self.device!.lockForConfiguration()
            } catch _ {
                NSLog("Error: lockForConfiguration.");
            }
            self.device!.videoZoomFactor = 1.5
            self.device!.unlockForConfiguration()
            
        }catch _ {
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        var stringValue:String?
        if metadataObjects.count > 0 {
            let metadataObject = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            stringValue = metadataObject.stringValue
            
            if stringValue != nil{
                self.session.stopRunning()
            }
        }
        self.session.stopRunning()
        
    }
    
}
```

[image: img]